# Has canonicity changed in Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the past people used to say that the Dragon Ball manga was canon and the series was not, because Toriyama drew the manga and he didnt do the same with the series. But now that Toriyama doesnt draw the manga anymore but Toyotaro based in his ideas, both the manga and the series are adaptations of Toriyama's ideas. Is the Dragon Ball manga still the canon for Dragon Ball or it isnt anymore?

Answer (score 1):

The dragonball manga is still canon for the original series.

For Dragonball super, both the manga and the anime can be considered canon. They are simply two continuities. You can talk about the manga continuity and the anime continuity. One is not more canon than the other.